# Simultaneous assignment semantics in Python

Tags: python, variable-assignment, semantics, simultaneous

Consider the following Python 3 code:

```
a = [-1,-1,-1]
i = 0
```

And now consider the following two versions of a simultaneous assignment over both a and i:

Assignment version 1:

```
a[i],i = i,i+1
```

Assignment version 2:

```
i,a[i] = i+1,i
```

I would expect these two versions of simultaneous assignments to be semantically equivalent. However, if you check the values of a and i after each one of the simultaneous assignments, you get different states:

Output for `print(a,i)` after assignment version 1:

```
[0, -1, -1] 1
```

Output for `print(a,i)` after assignment version 2:

```
[-1, 0, -1] 1
```

I am not an expert on Python's semantics, but this behaviour seems weird. I would expect both assignments to behave as assignment version 1. Moreover, if you check the following link, one would expect both assignment versions to lead to the same state:

[Link to book excerpt in Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=aJQILlLxRmAC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=python%20simultaneous%20assignment&source=bl&ots=Cz9MCJYb1J&sig=vG_ZhffOwiOJgejxK8uih-SlmDk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f1WIUcXVFfa44AOB04HwAQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=python%20simultaneous%20assignment&f=false)

Is there something I am missing regarding Python semantics for simultaneous assignments?

*Note*: This weird behaviour does not seem to be reproducible, for instance, when the variable `a` has integer type; it seems to require `a` to be of type list (maybe this is the case for any mutable type?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case:

```
i, a[i] = i + 1, i
```

The righthand side evaluates to a tuple (1, 0). This tuple is then unpacked to `i` and then `a[i]`. `a[i]` is evaluated *during* the unpacking, not before, so corresponds to `a[1]`.

Since the righthand side is evaluated before any unpacking takes place, referring to `a[i]` on the righthand side would always be `a[0]` regardless of the final value of `i`

Here is another useless fun example for you to work out

```
>>> a = [0,0,0,0]
>>> i, a[i], i, a[i] = range(4)
>>> a
[1, 0, 3, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you gnibbler, I see the technical point you raise about the evaluation to tuples; from that point of view all makes perfect sense. However, I am still at a loss from a semantics viewpoint since then the _simultaneous_ assignment semantics is then not very simultaneous. Since I am new to Python, I would take my chances and ask if there is an official document with a formal/semi-formal definition of the assignment semantics for Python. Are you aware of any such a document?

Comment: @hquilo: "simultaneous assignment" doesn't even appear in the Python documentation. `a, b = 1, 2` is just shorthand for `(a, b) = (1, 2)`, which is called sequence unpacking.

Comment: Thank you both @gnibler and @Blender; your answers make things clear.

Comment: Just to add a reference to the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html): "Although the definition of assignment implies that overlaps between the left-hand side and the right-hand side are ‘simultaneous’ (for example `a, b = b, a` swaps two variables), overlaps _within_ the collection of assigned-to variables occur left-to-right, sometimes resulting in confusion."