# Swapping elements of numpy 2d-array by a simultaneuous assignment overwrites the elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, swap

I usually use Python as one of my main programming languages.

I observed that swapping rows of numpy 2d-array by a simultaneous assignment overwrites the elements. What I felt to be odd is this overwrite only happened for:

- 2d-array

and, did not happen for:

- list_of_list
- list_of_array
- array_1d
- list_of_numbers

(Please refer a following "Case 1" result.)

I want to know the mechanism of this behavior. Here is my test code:

```
import numpy as np
def swap(seq):
    '''swaps first two elemnts'''
    print('Before swapping\n', seq)
    seq[0], seq[1] = seq[1], seq[0]
    print('After swapping\n', seq)
    print('')

print('Case 1: array_2d')
array_2d = np.arange(8).reshape(4, 2)
swap(array_2d)

print('Case 2: list_of_list')
list_of_list = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
swap(list_of_list)

print('Case 3: list_of_array')
list_of_array = [np.array([0, 1]),
                 np.array([2, 3]),
                 np.array([4, 5]),
                 np.array([6, 7])]
swap(list_of_array)

print('Case 4: array_1d')
array_1d = np.arange(4)
swap(array_1d)

print('Case 5: list_of_numbers')
list_of_numbers = list(range(4))
swap(list_of_numbers)
```

Results are:

```
Case 1: array_2d
Before swapping
 [[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]]
After swapping
 [[2 3]  # <- failed to swap
 [2 3]   # <- failed to swap
 [4 5]
 [6 7]]

Case 2: list_of_list
Before swapping
 [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
After swapping
 [[2, 3], [0, 1], [4, 5], [6, 7]]

Case 3: list_of_array
Before swapping
 [array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]), array([4, 5]), array([6, 7])]
After swapping
 [array([2, 3]), array([0, 1]), array([4, 5]), array([6, 7])]

Case 4: array_1d
Before swapping
 [0 1 2 3]
After swapping
 [1 0 2 3]

Case 5: list_of_numbers
Before swapping
 [0, 1, 2, 3]
After swapping
 [1, 0, 2, 3]
```

I found following posts related to simultaneous assignment, but still can not understand the above behavior.

*A solution using `.copy()` method.*

- [Swapping columns in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857927/swapping-columns-in-a-numpy-array)

*Assessment order of the simultaneous assignment.*

- [Multiple assignment and evaluation order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python)
- [Simultaneous assignment semantics in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409901/simultaneous-assignment-semantics-in-python)

I'm great appreciate for any kind of hints.

Thanks.

Comment: @hpauji Wow, my post seems totally duplicated. I understand that assignments of views caused