# Reversing a linked list(Iterative method)

Tags: python, linked-list

I am writing a code for reversing a linked list in python.
The following code does not pass the test case:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def reverseList(self, head)    
        prev, curr = None, head
        while curr:
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr 
            curr = curr.next
        return prev
```

while this code passes:

```
class Solution(object):        
    def reverseList(self, head):  # Iterative
        prev, curr = None, head
        while curr:
            curr.next, prev, curr = prev, curr, curr.next
        return prev
```

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Well, you can see which lines of code have been changed, right? So the question is really "why does that make a difference?", yes?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409901/simultaneous-assignment-semantics-in-python help you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your unrolled code, by the time you get to the last line, `curr.next` has been overwritten with `prev`.  It no longer has its original value.  Both `prev` and `curr` will point to the old `prev`.