# Is there any way to make this long if statement more concise?

Tags: python, if-statement, refactoring

Here is my long if statement:

```
   if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0:
       if x1 > x:
           ny = y + ceil(shift * (i / 2))
           ny1 = y1 + ceil(shift * (i / 2))
       elif x1 == x:
           ny = y
           ny1 = y1
       elif x1 < x:
           ny = y - ceil(shift * (i / 2))
           ny1 = y1 - ceil(shift * (i / 2))
       if y1 > y:
           nx = x - ceil(shift * (i / 2))
           nx1 = x1 - ceil(shift * (i / 2))
       elif y1 == y:
           nx = x
           nx1 = x1
       elif y1 < y:
           nx = x + ceil(shift * (i / 2))
           nx1 = x1 + ceil(shift * (i / 2))
   else:
       if x1 > x:
           ny = y - ceil(shift * (i / 2))
           ny1 = y1 - ceil(shift * (i / 2))
       elif x1 == x:
           ny = y
           ny1 = y1
       elif x1 < x:
           ny = y + ceil(shift * (i / 2))
           ny1 = y1 + ceil(shift * (i / 2))
       if y1 > y:
           nx = x + ceil(shift * (i / 2))
           nx1 = x1 + ceil(shift * (i / 2))
       elif y1 == y:
           nx = x
           nx1 = x1
       elif y1 < y:
           nx = x - ceil(shift * (i / 2))
           nx1 = x1 - ceil(shift * (i / 2))
   return nx, ny, nx1, ny1
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to just convert this whole thing into a simple equation. However, if not, is there any possible way to only have the first large if statement and make the sign in `ny = y + ceil(shift * (i / 2))` be plus `if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0` and minus `else`?

Comment: What exactly is the intended logic of it? Why do you think you need all these special cases? What do the `i`, `x`, `y`, `x1`, `y1` values represent? Why are you using the `ceil` function plus a bunch of special cases? Are you familiar with the `//` operator? Do you see how it might help you?

Comment: can i suggest you break it down by functions? having that long of an if statement is never recommended as it's most prone to edge cases

Comment: you can also try out "if not obj < obj2" which should alleviate some of the ongoing if statement

Comment: The third `elif` should just be `else:`

Comment: `ceil(shift * (i / 2))` appears many times. Assign that to a variable instead of repeating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This guy](https://www.diffchecker.com/diff) is your friend. Comparing the main `if` with its `else`, we'll see this:

[image]

This means that only the ceiling sign changes between branches. We can fix this by adding a new variable:

```
ceil_sign = 1 if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0 else -1

if x1 > x:
    ny = y + ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
    ny1 = y1 + ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

elif x1 == x:
    ny = y
    ny1 = y1

elif x1 < x:
    ny = y - ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
    ny1 = y1 - ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

if y1 > y:
    nx = x - ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
    nx1 = x1 - ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

elif y1 == y:
    nx = x
    nx1 = x1

elif y1 < y:
    nx = x + ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
    nx1 = x1 + ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
```

You can also move branches around:

```
ceil_sign = 1 if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0 else -1

if x1 > x:
    ny = y + ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
    ny1 = y1 + ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

elif x1 < x:
    ny = y - ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
    ny1 = y1 - ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

else:
    ny = y
    ny1 = y1

if y1 > y:
    nx = x - ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
    nx1 = x1 - ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

elif y1 < y:
    nx = x + ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
    nx1 = x1 + ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

else:
    nx = x
    nx1 = x1
```

This refactoring allow us to see even more differences: the first `if` and its `elif` also only changes the ceiling sign. Let's add another variable:

```
ceil_sign = 1 if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0 else -1

if x1 == x:
    ny = y
    ny1 = y1

else:
    x_ceil_sign = 1 if x1 > x else -1
    ny = y + x_ceil_sign * ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
    ny1 = y1 + x_ceil_sign * ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

if y1 == y:
    nx = x
    nx1 = x1

else:
    y_ceil_sign = 1 if y1 < y else -1
    nx = x + y_ceil_sign * ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
    nx1 = x1 + y_ceil_sign * ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))
```

---

As @Barmar suggested, note that `ceil_sign` always appears with the `ceil` call. You can combine them just once:

```
ceil_sign = 1 if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0 else -1
ceil_value = ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

if x1 == x:
    ny = y
    ny1 = y1

else:
    x_ceil_sign = 1 if x1 > x else -1
    ny = y + x_ceil_sign * ceil_value
    ny1 = y1 + x_ceil_sign * ceil_value

if y1 == y:
    nx = x
    nx1 = x1

else:
    y_ceil_sign = 1 if y1 < y else -1
    nx = x + y_ceil_sign * ceil_value
    nx1 = x1 + y_ceil_sign * ceil_value
```

You can do the same move with the internal `ceil_sign`s:

```
ceil_sign = 1 if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0 else -1
ceil_value = ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

if x1 == x:
    ny = y
    ny1 = y1

else:
    x_ceil_sign = (1 if x1 > x else -1) * ceil_value
    ny = y + x_ceil_sign
    ny1 = y1 + x_ceil_sign

if y1 == y:
    nx = x
    nx1 = x1

else:
    y_ceil_sign = (1 if y1 < y else -1) * ceil_value
    nx = x + y_ceil_sign
    nx1 = x1 + y_ceil_sign
```

Note that in both clauses, you're adding nothing on the `if` branch and adding `*_ceil_sign` in the `else` branch. Create another variable:

```
ceil_sign = 1 if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0 else -1
ceil_value = ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

x_factor = 0 if x1 == x else ((1 if x1 > x else -1) * ceil_value)
ny = y + x_factor
ny1 = y1 + x_factor

y_factor = 0 if y1 == y else ((1 if y1 < y else -1) * ceil_value)
nx = x + y_factor
nx1 = x1 + y_factor
```

---

As an additional refactoring, note that if a > b, sign(a - b) is equal to 1. You can use this to refactor the `*_factor` variables:

```
def sign(x):
    return 0 if x == 0 else 1 if x > 0 else -1

ceil_sign = 1 if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0 else -1
ceil_value = ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

x_factor = 0 if x1 == x else sign(x1 - x) * ceil_value
ny = y + x_factor
ny1 = y1 + x_factor

y_factor = 0 if y1 == y else -sign(y1 - y) * ceil_value
nx = x + y_factor
nx1 = x1 + y_factor
```

Also note that, if a == b, sign(a - b) is equal to 0, which defines both `*_factors`:

```
def sign(x):
    return 0 if x == 0 else 1 if x > 0 else -1

ceil_sign = 1 if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0 else -1
ceil_value = ceil_sign * ceil(shift * (i / 2))

x_factor = sign(x1 - x) * ceil_value
ny = y + x_factor
ny1 = y1 + x_factor

y_factor = -sign(y1 - y) * ceil_value
nx = x + y_factor
nx1 = x1 + y_factor
```

Comment: Can't you also combine `ceil_sign` with the `ceil()` call?

Comment: You're correct, didn't notice that

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints on how to approach problems like this generally:

1. Look for commonly repeated expressions, and name them.

Here, `ceil(shift * (i / 2))` happens a lot. Let's name that:

```
offset = ceil(shift * (i / 2))
if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0:
    if x1 > x:
        ny = y + offset
        ny1 = y1 + offset
    elif x1 == x:
        ny = y
        ny1 = y1
    elif x1 < x:
        ny = y - offset
        ny1 = y1 - offset
    if y1 > y:
        nx = x - offset
        nx1 = x1 - offset
    elif y1 == y:
        nx = x
        nx1 = x1
    elif y1 < y:
        nx = x + offset
        nx1 = x1 + offset
else:
    if x1 > x:
        ny = y - offset
        ny1 = y1 - offset
    elif x1 == x:
        ny = y
        ny1 = y1
    elif x1 < x:
        ny = y + offset
        ny1 = y1 + offset
    if y1 > y:
        nx = x + offset
        nx1 = x1 + offset
    elif y1 == y:
        nx = x
        nx1 = x1
    elif y1 < y:
        nx = x - offset
        nx1 = x1 - offset
return nx, ny, nx1, ny1
```

2. Use Python's [simultaneous assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409901/simultaneous-assignment-semantics-in-python) to group related assignments.

This is pretty straightforward:

```
offset = ceil(shift * (i / 2))
if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0:
    if x1 > x:
        ny, ny1 = y + offset, y1 + offset
    elif x1 == x:
        ny, ny1 = y, y1
    elif x1 < x:
        ny, ny1 = y - offset, y1 - offset
    if y1 > y:
        nx, nx1 = x - offset, x1 - offset
    elif y1 == y:
        nx, nx1 = x, x1
    elif y1 < y:
        nx, nx1 = x + offset, x1 + offset
else:
    if x1 > x:
        ny, ny1 = y - offset, y1 - offset
    elif x1 == x:
        ny, ny1 = y, y1
    elif x1 < x:
        ny, ny1 = y + offset, y1 + offset
    if y1 > y:
        nx, nx1 = x + offset, x1 + offset
    elif y1 == y:
        nx, nx1 = x, x1
    elif y1 < y:
        nx, nx1 = x - offset, x1 - offset
return nx, ny, nx1, ny1
```

3. Exploit symmetries and parallels. (The reason I make simple syntax tweaks like the simultaneous assignment *first* is that, by reducing the line count, we can bring symmetrical things visually closer together, and thus notice symmetry more easily.)

What I mean by a "symmetry" or "parallel" is that we do fundamentally the same thing with different variables (or a related thing with some small, patterned alteration). There are two of these here: first, there's the way that the code depends on the `i % 2 == 1 or i == 0`. We can quickly see that the effect of this - propagated through all the `if`/`elif` logic - is that when the condition is false, `offset` is subtracted where it would otherwise be added, and vice versa. We can use elementary algebra to simplify that, by simply replacing `offset` with `-offset` when the condition isn't met. Thus:

```
offset = ceil(shift * (i / 2))
if not(i % 2 == 1 or i == 0):
    offset = -offset
if x1 > x:
    ny, ny1 = y + offset, y1 + offset
elif x1 == x:
    ny, ny1 = y, y1
elif x1 < x:
    ny, ny1 = y - offset, y1 - offset
if y1 > y:
    nx, nx1 = x - offset, x1 - offset
elif y1 == y:
    nx, nx1 = x, x1
elif y1 < y:
    nx, nx1 = x + offset, x1 + offset
return nx, ny, nx1, ny1
```

4. Make algebraic simplifications.

Pattern recognition is useful here. We are doing *three-way comparisons*, and depending on that comparison we either *add, subtract or don't use* a given value. We could represent that "add, subtract or don't use" by instead multiplying our `offset` by 1, -1 or 0 respectively. If we extract that idea:

```
def threeway_compare(a1, a):
    if a1 > a:
        return 1
    elif a1 < a:
        return -1
    return 0 # a1 == a
```

then we find the hidden symmetry (i.e., we did that kind of three-way comparison twice):

```
offset = ceil(shift * (i / 2))
if not(i % 2 == 1 or i == 0):
    offset = -offset
y_offset = threeway_compare(x1, x)
ny, ny1 = y + y_offset, y1 + y_offset
# Since the changes made to the nx/nx1 values were reversed,
# we negate the comparison result before using it this way.
x_offset = -threeway_compare(y1, y)
nx, nx1 = x + x_offset, x1 + x_offset
return nx, ny, nx1, ny1
```

5. Scrap everything and try a different approach.

Sometimes this is called for. In this particular case, using `ceil` in order to calculate an "adjustment" is a warning sign that something is going wrong. It might have been better to compute the `nx` etc. values directly, rather than computing `x` etc. and then having to adjust them in this way. Perhaps this indicates something wrong about the original question.